# EntityFramework Core sometimes rounds average to 2 decimal places

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.0

When I call Average method on a decimal column that has SQL type of `DECIMAL (18,8)` I sometimes get my value rounded to 2 decimal places and sometimes not.

When I print it to console I get something like `0.010000` and `0.021232` so it seems like this happens whenever the value is less than 0.01.

I tried setting data type explicitly using `ModelBuilder` but it doesn't change anything.

While I was writing this questions I check SQL profiler and found the problem. When EF sends a query it casts the column to `DECIMAL(18,2)`

So the question now becomes 'Why would they do this and how can I select desired precision?' Is this a bug or a feature?

Comment: Before you answer I'd like to let you know that I found a temporary fix by materializing the list of values and then calling Average on it and it returns correct results.

Comment: Sounds like a bug. But only EF Core team members can answer why is that.

Comment: Can you [submit a new issue](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/new) showing the query and what data type you tried setting with `ModelBuilder`?

Comment: Here's a link to the defect I posted https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/11885